# why tesseract detect not correct in a good image?

Tags: tesseract, emgucv

i'm a newbie in computer vision.
i using emguCV v3.2 for my application and tesseract version 3.0 
my application is detect number of electric meter.. 
i used file data language for tesseract download here:
  https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/master/eng.traineddata
after preprocess image then i have image below. but tesseract detect to: **033478**
i can not understand why tesseract detect not correct number 6 to number 8??

[number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ0DO.png)

Comment: Who has problems like me?? pls help me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the image isn't optimized try to do some preprocessing optimization.
Here is a tutorial that walks you through the preprocessing [tuto](https://mazira.com/blog/optimal-image-conversion-settings-tesseract-ocr), for me the ghost script was sufficient